# Facebook-javascript-sdk without app

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a simple question:

Can I use the facebook-javascript-sdk in a stand-alone webpage without having to create an app? I do not want an app, nor do I need one, I just want to run a script to retrieve a list of the people who have liked the current user's page.

I can use javascript to move on from there, but I'm getting hung up on FB.init() and its appid. For example, it's complaining that FB.getLoginStatus() is called before FB.init(), but calling FB.init() again from the console says that I've called it again, indicating a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from my understanding this is how that works,

If you want to have a `like button` on your page you do not have to have an `appid` or `appsecret`
All you have to do to make this work is leave the `appid` section off of the api call. 
You can find some information about that here,

This is from Stackoverflow 2012 so it could be outdated.

Now if you are trying to get access to your users personal information, or something from their facebook page as their likes or their friends likes. You need an `appid` and `appsecret`.

If you are intimidated getting an app up and running I made a quick app to help people get that done. 
It is a login script with 3 lines of code you need to change and it shows you how to make an api call and display information. You can grab that app from [My GitHub Here](https://github.com/wuno/Facebook-Login-Example)

Just follow the instructions in the `Readme file`

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Unfortunately, the Example didn't work for me. The other link you posted, however, bore unexpected results. I found a piece of the puzzle thanks to @Sparky in that an "app" can just be a website, nothing more. Also, I found this link to be of use as well: [Facebook Bugs](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/147185208750426)